# Can't convert String to Numeric/Decimal in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have five or six OLE DB Sources with a String[DT_STR], with a length of 500 and 1252 (Latin) as Code Page.
The format of the column is like *0,08* or *0,10* etc etc. As you can see, it is separated with a comma. 
All of them are equal except one of them. In this one source, I have a POINT as separation. On this it is working when I set the Data Type in the advanced editor of the OLE DB Source. On another (with comma separated) it is also working, if I set the Data Type in the advanced editor of the OLE DB Source. BUT the weird thing is, that it isn't working with the other sources although they are the same (sperated with comma).

I tested Numeric(18,2) and decimal(2).

Another try to solve the problem with the conversion task and/or the derived column task, failed.

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2

Slowly, I think SSIS is fooling me :)

Has anyone an idea?

/// EDIT
Here a two screens:

Is working:
[click](http://abload.de/img/isworkingmbkv1.jpg)
[image]

Isn't working:
[click](http://abload.de/img/isntworkinge4jh1.jpg)
[image]

Comment: When you say 'not working' means are you getting any error message, if so could you please provide  it.

Comment: Yep you are right. I'm getting an error message. Error message: "[OLE DB Source [4990]] Error: There was an error with output column "offer vatFactor" (5061) on output "OLE DB Source Output" (5000). The column status returned was: "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data."."

Comment: I also get "Invalid character value for cast specification" when I use the data conversion or derived column task. But I tested the rows with ... where [offer vatfactor] NOT LIKE '[0-9][,][0-9][0-9]' and there are no invalid characters.

Answer (score 1):

I would not set the Data Type in the Advanced Editor of the OLE DB Source.  I would convert the data in the SQL Code of the OLE DB Source, or in a Script Transformation e.g. using Decimal.TryParse , which would update a new column.

SSIS is unbeleivably fussy over datatypes and trying to mess with its internals is not productive.

Answer (score 0):

Check that there are any spaces in between the commas, so that the SSIS is throwing an error trying to convert the blank space to a number. A blank space does not equal nothing in between spaces.

Redirect error rows and output the data to a file. Then you can examine the data that is being rejected by the SSIS and determine why it's causing error.

Reason for the error

1) Null’s are not properly handled either in the destination database or during SSIS package creation. It is quite possible that the source contains a null database but the destination is not accepting the NULL data leading to build generate above error.

2) Data types between source and destination does not match. For example, source column has varchar data and destination column have an int data type. This can easily generate above error. There are certain kind of datatypes which will automatically convert to another data type and will not generate the error but there are for incompatible datatypes which will generate `The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.` error.

Comment: Ok now I have redirected the error rows to two different tables. One for the conversion task and the second for the derived column task. I have several column that are procressed in this two task. So it is actually necessary to find out which column creates the error. For that problem I found this little tutorial: http://sqlage.blogspot.de/2013/12/ssis-how-to-get-error-column-name-in.html but I don't know how the expression should look like  q STEP 4 -> DER_DFT_Name. Thanks for your comment, has helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

The Issue arises when there is unhandled **space** or **null**. I have worked around using the Conditional (Ternary) Operator which checks the length:

```
LEN(TRIM([Column Name])) >= 1 ? (DT_NUMERIC,38,8)[Column Name] : 0
```